# Doorbird intercom: "Please check your inputs"

Tags: networking, home-networking, iot

I'm setting up a Doorbird home intercom / video doorbell on my home network.

I'm trying to log in at https://webadmin.doorbird.com/login

The documentation says:

> The administrator username and password can be found in the document “QUICKSTART GUIDE / DIGITAL PASSPORT“.

I'm using the username and password from this document included with the hardware unit.

But upon logging in, I get the error:

> Please check your inputs

What is wrong? Why can't I log in?

---

[image: Doorbird: Please check your inputs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that your Doorbird unit is connected to the Internet.

In my case the Doorbird had PoE power and appeared to be connected. But one of the ethernet twisted strands had broken when being wired.

The error:

> Please check your inputs

is given when the Doorbird cannot be reached, in addition to a wrong username/password or other such login error.